# URLRequest(url: webURL!) is returning NIL

Tags: ios, swift

I am just starting on IOS/SWIFT and I am running though some basic tasks...

I have seem to run across an issue I can not figure out nor understand the issue.

I want to display the webpage in my web view but the optional value is returning NIL but holds a value line before...

```
    if let address = webSite {
        let webURL = URL(string: address) //webURL=="google.com" at this point 
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
```

urlRequest is NILL after trying the URLRequest..even tho webURL holds a value of "google.com"
Which then results in the loadRequest crashing with the error

```
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

I believe I understand the concept of the optional value that it will return NILL if it holds no value but I can produce the value of "google.com" at URL call.

Comment: Try `http://google.com`. Your current url is not actually a valid url, so `webURL` is `nil`.

Comment: which line is actually causing the crash, are you sure the code you posted actually is related to the error?

Comment: I would guess `webView` is `nil`.

Comment: I tried http:// - No difference. And the error is coming on the loadRequest because the var urlRequest is NILL

Comment: no, because `webView` is `nil`, `urlRequest` cannot even be `nil` .

Comment: you must use `http://www.google.com` and also config http in info.plist

Comment: you can check `if let x = y { } ` for handle your error when `URL` is nil

Comment: The reason is your webView is nil, please initialise the webView

Answer (score 0):

Please unwrap optional `webURL` like below,

```
if let address = webSite, let webURL = URL(string: address) {
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webURL)
    webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
}
```

Also verify webView is properly initialized or connected in `storyboard`

Answer (score 0):

Its better to check whether URL is successfully created or not?. For your case it is for sure that `URL(string: address)` is not able to create a valid URL and force wnwrapping (putting `!` mark) crashing the app.

**Update your code as:**

```
   if let address = webSite, let webURL = URL(string: address) {
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webURL)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
```

Comment: This is still giving me a "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the loadRequest call